# Pascal compiles and closes straight away despite readln;

Tags: pascal, readline

```
program words;
uses crt;
type
    T2DArray = array[1..100, 1..100] of string;
var
    ch:char;
    x,y:integer;
    MapArray: T2DArray;
begin
    x:=0;
    y:=0;
    repeat
            MapArray[10, 10] := 'you are at a tree';
            writeln(MapArray[x,y]);
            write('current positon is ');
            write(x);write(',');write(y);
            ch:=ReadKey;
            case ch of
            #0 : begin
                    ch:=ReadKey; {Read ScanCode}
                    case ch of
                    'w'  :  y:=y+1;
                    'a'  :  x:=x-1;
                    's'  :  y:=y-1;
                    'd'  :  x:=x+1;
                    end;
            end;
            #27 : WriteLn('ESC');
            end;
    until ch=#27;
    readln;
end.
```

i have this simple piece of code that will allow me to assign things to XY coordinates of a 2d array. the code compiles and closes straight away despite the readln; at the bottom. 
All the best Arran.

Comment: What happens when you step through it in the debugger? (Also, you tagged your question "syntax error". There is no syntax error if it compiles and runs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always enable range-checking {$R+} during development. You have a 1-based array but your x and y values are zero the first time you read from it.